# OR Tools - maintanance service planning application

Tags: or-tools

Imagine problem like - there are clients (nodes) which one repairman have to visit to do some maintenance there. It takes him some time on each location to do the work. It also takes him some time to travel between clients. Clients are home just in specific time intervals. As per this assignment it is pretty close to OR Tools VRPTW. The main difference is that there is no consideration for the time it takes repairman to do maintenance on place. I have tried to model this requirement like this:
I make time windows from clients availability intervals

```
time_window[i] = (client[i]_becomes_available, client[i]_in_no_more_longer_available - maintenance_duration[i])
```

The time it takes repairman to travel between node[i] and node[i+1] is duration of maintenance[i]. So the time matrix has rows full of same numbers except for diagonal, because it takes same time to 'travel' from particular node to all others. I was wondering whether VRPTW is even suitable for an assignment like that?

I have tried to customize VRPTW example to suit my assignment. Here is the code with time windows and time matrix computed as per my assignment:

```
"""Vehicles Routing Problem (VRP) with Time Windows."""
import math
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data['time_matrix'] = None
    data['time_windows'] = None
    data['num_vehicles'] = 1
    data['depot'] = None
    return data
def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Prints solution on console."""
    print(f'Objective: {solution.ObjectiveValue()}')
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Time')
    total_time = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
            plan_output += '{0} Time({1},{2}) -> '.format(
                manager.IndexToNode(index), solution.Min(time_var),
                solution.Max(time_var))
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
        time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
        plan_output += '{0} Time({1},{2})\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index),
                                                    solution.Min(time_var),
                                                    solution.Max(time_var))
        plan_output += 'Time of the route: {}min\n'.format(
            solution.Min(time_var))
        print(plan_output)
        total_time += solution.Min(time_var)
    print('Total time of all routes: {}min'.format(total_time))
def make_routing_monitor(routing_model: pywrapcp.RoutingModel, failure_limit: int) -> callable:
    class RoutingMonitor:
        def __init__(self, model: pywrapcp.RoutingModel):
            self.model = model
            self._counter = 0
            self._best_objective = math.inf
            self._counter_limit = failure_limit

        def __call__(self):
            print("SOLUTION FOUND !")
            self._best_objective = min(self._best_objective, self.model.CostVar().Max())
            if self._best_objective == self.model.CostVar().Max():
                self._counter = 0
            else:
                self._counter += 1
                if self._counter > self._counter_limit:
                    self.model.solver().FinishCurrentSearch()
    return RoutingMonitor(routing_model)

def main():
    INPUT_DATA_SWITCH = 1
    timespan_end = 7290

    """Solve the VRP with time windows."""
    # Instantiate the data problem.
    data = create_data_model()

    # DATA FOR WHICH SOLUTION IS FOUND
    if INPUT_DATA_SWITCH:
        data['time_matrix'] = [
            [    0,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,     0],
            [   75,     0,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,     0],
            [  240,   240,     0,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,     0],
            [   75,    75,    75,     0,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,     75,     0],
            [   30,    30,    30,    30,     0,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,     30,     0],
            [  120,   120,   120,   120,   120,     0,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,     120,     0],
            [  135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,     0,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,     135,     0],
            [   30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,     0,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,     30,     0],
            [  180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,     0,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,     180,     0],
            [   75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,     0,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,     75,     0],
            [   75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,     0,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,     75,     0],
            [  315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,     0,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,     315,     0],
            [  120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,     0,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,     120,     0],
            [   30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,     0,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,     30,     0],
            [  165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,     0,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,     165,     0],
            [   60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,     0,    60,    60,    60,    60,      60,     0],
            [  135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,     0,   135,   135,   135,     135,     0],
            [  225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,     0,   225,   225,     225,     0],
            [  330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,     0,   330,     330,     0],
            [  330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,     0,     330,     0],
            [   60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,     0,       0,     0],
            [    0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,       0,     0]]

        data['time_windows'] = [(0, 72900), (30, 1755), (30, 1590), (30, 1755), (30, 1800), (30, 1710), (30, 1695), (1110, 2880), (1110, 2730),
                                (30, 1755), (30, 1755), (30, 1515), (30, 1710), (30, 1800), (1110, 2745), (1110, 2850), (1110, 2775), (1110, 2685),
                                (2550, 4020), (2550, 4020), (2550, 4290), (100, 72900)]

    # DATA FOR WHICH SOLUTION IS NOT FOUND (+ 1 PLACE)
    else:
        data['time_matrix'] = [
            [    0,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,     30,     0], #0
            [   75,     0,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,     75,     0], #1
            [  240,   240,     0,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,    240,     0], #2
            [   75,    75,    75,     0,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,     75,    75,     0], #3
            [   30,    30,    30,    30,     0,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,     30,    30,     0], #4
            [  120,   120,   120,   120,   120,     0,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,     120,  120,     0], #5
            [  135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,     0,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,     135,  135,     0], #6
            [   30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,     0,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,     30,    30,     0], #7
            [  180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,     0,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,   180,     180,   180,    0], #8
            [   75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,     0,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,     75,    75,     0], #9
            [   75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,     0,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,    75,     75,    75,     0], #10
            [  315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,     0,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,   315,     315,   315,    0], #11
            [  120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,     0,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,   120,     120,   120,    0], #12
            [   30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,     0,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,    30,     30,    30,     0], #13
            [  165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,     0,   165,   165,   165,   165,   165,     165,   165,    0], #14
            [   60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,     0,    60,    60,    60,    60,      60,   60,     0], #15
            [  135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,   135,     0,   135,   135,   135,     135,   135,    0], #16
            [  225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,   225,     0,   225,   225,     225,   225,    0], #17
            [  330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,     0,   330,     330,   330,    0], #18
            [  330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,   330,     0,     330,   330,    0], #19
            [   60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,    60,       0,   60,     0], #20
            [  240,   240,   240,    240,  240,  240,    240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,   240,     240,    0,     0], #21
            [    0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,       0,    0,     0]] #22
        #       0       1       2      3     4      5      6      7      8      9      10     11     12     13     14     15     16     17     18     19       20    21     22

        data['time_windows'] = [(0, 72900), (30, 1755), (30, 1590), (30, 1755), (30, 1800), (30, 1710), (30, 1695), (1110, 2880), (1110, 2730),
                                (30, 1755), (30, 1755), (30, 1515), (30, 1710), (30, 1800), (1110, 2745), (1110, 2850), (1110, 2775), (1110, 2685),
                                (2550, 4020), (2550, 4020), (2550, 4290), (30, 1590), (100, 72900)]

    data['depot'] = len(data['time_windows']) - 1 # index of dummy depot node

    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['time_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], [0], [data['depot']]) # starting at initial condition - order from previous week
    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    # Create and register a transit callback.
    def time_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the travel time between the two nodes."""
        return data['time_matrix'][from_index][to_index]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)

    # Define cost of each arc.
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)
    routing.AddAtSolutionCallback(make_routing_monitor(routing, 10))

    # Add Time Windows constraint.
    time = 'Time'
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        500,  # allow waiting time, this is maximum waiting time of the line
        timespan_end,  # maximum time per vehicle
        False,  # Don't force start cumul to zero.
        time)
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(time)
    # Add time window constraints for each location except depot.
    for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data['time_windows']):
        if location_idx == data['depot']:
            continue
        index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])
    # Add time window constraints for each vehicle start node.
    depot_idx = data['depot']
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(
            data['time_windows'][depot_idx][0],
            data['time_windows'][depot_idx][1])

    # Instantiate route start and end times to produce feasible times.
    for i in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i)))
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)))

    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.LOCAL_CHEAPEST_INSERTION)

    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    # Print solution on console.
    if solution:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)

    print("Solver status: ", routing.status())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There is INPUT_DATA_SWITCH variable, which changes input data for which it is solved or not. The only difference in datasets is one additional node in the second dataset.

I have noticed, that solver is allowed to wait some time on nodes. I thought this could be the problem because when there is some wait time on place/node it should shorten the duration[i] of current node, because repairman starts his job right after arrival. But it doesn't as the time matrix is static. But it is just my assumption. Please, can someone give me some hint on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm solving the exact same problem :) - how did you end up approaching yours? The CVRPTW example given by or-tools is spot on, especially this piece of the code that handles service times:

```
for from_node in range(data['num_locations']):
        _total_time[from_node] = {}
        for to_node in range(data['num_locations']):
            if from_node == to_node:
                _total_time[from_node][to_node] = 0
            else:
                _total_time[from_node][to_node] = int(
                    service_time(data, from_node) +
                    travel_time(data, from_node, to_node))
```

(emphasis added). Time windows should only define the time from A to B, not the service time at A or B. I used this as the base to modify my code to suit.